# Dynamic aggregation on data with constraint

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, design-patterns, hazelcast

I have some data and an aggregator. In my project I'm using Hazelcast Jet and Java.

I have two devices (A, B) monitored and two customer that watch a dashboard. The first can see only A and the second can see A and B.

If A goes offline, the first will see 0 device on and the second will see 1 device on.

How Can I Aggregate the data, based on customer visibility?

Potentially I could have 10000 devices and 1000 different customer visibility, so doing 1000 or more different query (aggregation) in real-time can be heavy on the system.

Is there any known pattern to manage this situation?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward using Hazelcast Jet.   Assuming there is some sort of data field in the data stream which represents the customer, you can use that as a groupingKey in a pipeline stage, then provide your needed aggregation logic in an aggregate() or rollingAggregate() pipeline stage.

If you don't have customer in the data stream but have some device ID that can be mapped to a customer, then this mapping can be done in a map() pipeline stage before the grouping and aggregation.

Then you can drain the aggregated data to whatever data sink is appropriate where the clients can access it.   It could be written to a map keyed by the customer key, or you could be publishing a stream to a client-specific topic (JMS, Kafka, or similar)